# How can I get a list of files in my storage bucket using Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm trying to write a simple function that will iterate over all the files I have in a folder in Firebase storage using a Firebase Cloud Function. I have spent hours trying every example online and reading the documentation.

This is what I currently have:

```
exports.removeUnsizedImages = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun((context) => {

    const storage = admin.storage();
    var storageRef = storage.ref();

    storageRef.listAll().then(function(result) {
        console.log("*", result);
    })
});
```

I'm getting an error that storage.ref() is not a function.

If I try:

```
storage.listAll()
```

It also tells me that listAll is not a function.

I really didn't think it would be this hard to just get the files in a folder.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATED CODE THAT NOW WORKS**

```
exports.removeUnsizedImages = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 24 hours').onRun((context) => {
    
    admin.storage().bucket().getFiles({ prefix: "postImages/" }).then(function(data) {
        const files = data[0];

        files.forEach(function(image) {
            console.log("***** ", image.name)
        })

    });
    
});
```

Comment: You should returned the promises returned by the asynchronous work, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions. Something like `return admin.storage().bucket().getFiles({ prefix: "postImages/" }).then(function(data) { const files = data[0]; ... return null; });`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`listAll`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files#list_all_files) you are using is a function in the Firebase Storage Client SDK and not the Admin SDK.

To get all files in the Admin SDK, try this:

```
const allFiles = await admin.storage().bucket().getFiles({ prefix: "/user/images" })
```

> Here prefix is the path which you want to list.
>
> - If you just specify prefix = 'a/', you'll get back:
> - /a/1.txt
> - /a/b/2.txt
> - However, if you specify prefix='a/' and delimiter='/', you'll get back:
> - /a/1.txt

You can just use `.getFiles()` to get the whole bucket. More details can be found in the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles)

Comment: Thanks so much! This was exactly what I was looking for.